# Let a user 'subscribe' to categories

Tags: categories

Does anyone know if I can allow a member to subscribe to categories.

For example, for an automotive blog, with categories such as: Motorbike, Cars, Classic Cars, Motorhomes. As a user I would be able to login, choose the categories they were interested in, say Classic Cars and Motorbikes, and then only see posts that belong to that category.

Basically I want members to be able to personalise their feed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Member Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/member-categories) module and let users assign themselves to the categories that they like using [{exp:member_categories:form}](http://www.intoeetive.com/docs/member_categories.html#assign)  tag and then [display entries in their categories](http://www.intoeetive.com/docs/member_categories.html#related)